# Imagemagick to Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Imagick has documentation. But i struck with some functions.

```
exec($convert.'  '.$jpg.' -colorspace gray -sigmoidal-contrast 10,40%  -fill "#99cccc" -compose Hardlight  -composite  '.$png1);
exec("$convert -size 184x244 xc:transparent  ".$png1."   -set option:distort:viewport 184x244   -matte -virtual-pixel transparent  -distort Perspective '0,0,0,39  0,203,36,244  153,0,136,0  153,203,184,224'  -composite  ".$png."");
```

To convert this function i started with

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage($image);
$im->setColorspace(IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE);
$im->sigmoidalContrastImage(false, '40%', 10); // i am sure about this line.
```

For fill I did something like this. Not sure about this too.

```
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('#99cccc');

$im->drawImage($draw);
$im->setImageCompose(COMPOSITE_HARDLIGHT);
```

I don't know how to start to do the xc:transparent and $png1
set option, matte virtual-pixel and distort have good documentation. I can follow them.

Both of the exec has -composite at the end. How do i do that in imagick?

Thanks!